# Docker Container run のエラーについて

Tags: windows, docker

Dockerfileのイメージをビルドし,コンテナの起動を行っていますが、エラーが表示されてしまいます。

```
Run 'docker COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.
```

構文が間違っているようではないと思うのですが、おかしな点はありますでしょうか？
ご教示ください。

以下に、実行したコマンド（処理）も記載します。

**Dockerfike**

```
FROM python
WORKDIR /tmp/mydir
COPY ./ex01 /tmp/mydir/
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

**Docker image**

```
PS C:\PC-Work\dockerenv\ex01> docker image ls
REPOSITORY       TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
img_ex01_py_01   latest    5056c1313323   13 minutes ago   932MB
```

**Docker container run実行結果**

```
# img_ex01_py_01というイメージからtestpyというコンテナを作成・起動
docker countainer run -it --name testpy img_ex01_py_01


Run 'docker COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.

To get more help with docker, check out our guides at https://docs.docker.com/go/guides/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> docker countainer run -it --name testpy img_ex01_py_01
> ```

`countainer`ではなく`container`と記述する必要があります。

---

ちなみに使用されているDockerのバージョンは何になりますでしょうか？
手元の20.10.20ではエラーメッセージを再現することができませんでした。
前質問の件もあり、想定していないdockerが稼働していたりしないか気になりました。

ファイルの場所の確認

```
PS> Get-Command docker | Format-List

Name            : docker.exe
CommandType     : Application
Definition      : C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe
Extension       : .exe
Path            : C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe
FileVersionInfo : File:             C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe
                  InternalName:
                  OriginalFilename:
                  FileVersion:
                  FileDescription:
                  Product:
                  ProductVersion:
                  Debug:            False
                  Patched:          False
                  PreRelease:       False
                  PrivateBuild:     False
                  SpecialBuild:     False
                  Language:
```

バージョン表示

```
PS> docker -v
Docker version 20.10.20, build 9fdeb9c
```

コマンドが誤っている場合

```
PS> docker countainer run
docker: 'countainer' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

`container`のサブコマンドが誤っている場合

```
PS> docker container ran

Usage:  docker container COMMAND

Manage containers

Commands:
  attach      Attach local standard input, output, and error streams to a running container
  commit      Create a new image from a container's changes
  cp          Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
  create      Create a new container
  diff        Inspect changes to files or directories on a container's filesystem
  exec        Run a command in a running container
  export      Export a container's filesystem as a tar archive
  inspect     Display detailed information on one or more containers
  kill        Kill one or more running containers
  logs        Fetch the logs of a container
  ls          List containers
  pause       Pause all processes within one or more containers
  port        List port mappings or a specific mapping for the container
  prune       Remove all stopped containers
  rename      Rename a container
  restart     Restart one or more containers
  rm          Remove one or more containers
  run         Run a command in a new container
  start       Start one or more stopped containers
  stats       Display a live stream of container(s) resource usage statistics
  stop        Stop one or more running containers
  top         Display the running processes of a container
  unpause     Unpause all processes within one or more containers
  update      Update configuration of one or more containers
  wait        Block until one or more containers stop, then print their exit codes

Run 'docker container COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.
```

→ 仮に質問文が誤記で`container`の綴りが正しければ、`Run 'docker container COMMAND --help'`とサブコマンドのヘルプを参照するよう表示されるはずであり、 `Run 'docker COMMAND --help'` と表示されるのはコマンドが特定できていないと思われる。

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
docker container run -it --name testpy img_ex01_py_01
```